# Check current foreground terminal ("lsvt" like "chvt")

Tags: linux, terminal

"chvt N" lets me switch to foreground terminal N, the same as pushing 
alt-ctrl-FN.

What command line program tells me what terminal I'm currently using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fgconsole` prints the number of the active VT.

Answer (score 3):

This command tells you what terminal you are using:

```
tty
```

This command tells you what virtual terminal is currently active:

```
head -n 1 /sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/active
```

The two are not necessarily equivalent.  There are other sorts of terminals than virtual terminals, after all.